# Finding initial pressure in a chemical equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, ideal-gas

Consider the equilibrium below. If $K = 4$ and initial pressures of $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ are equal, giving a total pressure of $1.5~\mathrm{bar}$ at equilibrium. What was the initial pressure of $\ce{CO}$ or $\ce{H2O}$?

$$\ce{CO(g) + H2O (g) <=> CO2 (g) + H2 (g)}$$

I don't know how to get the initial pressures in this situation. Do I have to set up an ICE chart? I'm not sure how to start, any help would be appreciated. The answer is apparently $0.75~\mathrm{bar}$.

Comment: Are we meant to assume that the system initially has no $\ce{H_2} \text{ or } \ce{CO_2}$?

Answer (score 1):

If the initial pressure of $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{H_2O}$ are equal, then let $p_{\ce{H_2O}}=p_{\ce{CO}}=x$.

Since their total is 1.5 bar, i.e. $\ce{p_{H_2O} + p_{CO}}=1.5$

Can you solve this equation?

---

Edit: This is under the assumption that there was originally no carbon dioxide or hydrogen, I have not yet managed to generalise it to any case.

It is given that $K=4$. From the equation for the equilibrium constant, $K=\frac{\ce{[CO2][H2]}}{\ce{[CO][H2O]}}$.

It is also given that initially, $\ce{p_{H2O} = p_{\ce{CO}}}$; from the ideal gas law,

$PV=nRT \implies P=\frac{nRT}{V}=kC  \tag{1}$

where $k$ is some constant and C is concentration.

So initially, $[\ce{H2O}]=[\ce{CO}]=y$, where $y$ is a constant. Let the concentration consumed by the equilibrium shifting to the right be x.

At equilibrium, $\frac{\ce{[CO2][H_2]}}{[\ce{CO}][\ce{H2O}]}=\frac{x^2}{(y-x)^2}=4$.

Solving this equation gives $x=\frac{2y}{3}$.

Now then, if you look back at (1), pressure is proportional to concentration. Try to use that relationship to solve the problem.

> Now, from $(1)$, we see that pressure is directly proportional to concentration. We have worked out from our algebra that: $[\ce{CO2}]=[\ce{H2}]=\frac{2y}{3}$, therefore $[\ce{CO}]=[\ce{H2O}]=\frac{y}{3}$.

So then $p_{\ce{H2}}= p_{\ce{CO2}} = 2p_{\ce{CO}} = 2p_{\ce{H2O}}$ at equilibrium.

So from substitution into Martin's equation, $\ce{p_{H_2O} + p_{CO} + p_{\ce{CO2}} + p_{\ce{H2}}}=1.5$, we find that $p_{\ce{H2O}} = p_{\ce{CO}} = \pu{0.25 bar}$.

But they are now only a third of their original concentration, and so their pressure has also decreased by a factor of 3. So their original pressure is $\pu{0.75 bar}$ each.

Comment: I am not so sure, this is the right (generic) way to solve this problem, since it is given as $$p_e(\ce{CO}) + p_e(\ce{H2O}) + p_e(\ce{CO2}) + p_e(\ce{H2}) = 1.5~\mathrm{bar}$$

Comment: @Martin Is it possible to solve this for the case where there is some $\ce{CO_2}$ or $\ce{H_2}$ present in varying amounts? I can't seem to do the algebra..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, do you refer to $p(\ce{CO2})\neq p(\ce{H2})$ at equilibrium?|| I highly recommend you use a clearer way of presenting your calculations. I was initially not able to follow your thoughts, until I did the calculation myself. Using $K$ in two instances is never a good idea (substitution of physical properties with a nameless variable $x$ is usually not a good idea.)

Comment: Yes, that and my assumption that there was no $\ce{CO_2}$ or $\ce{H_2}$ initially. And thanks for pointing that out, I shall endeavour to clean it up and make it easier to follow in future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found using an ICE table. We let the initial partial pressures of $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ be $x$, and assign an arbitrary value $y$ to the change.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &\ce{CO}  & \ce{H2O}  & \ce{CO2}  & \ce{H2}   \\
\hline
 p_0      & x  & x   & 0    & 0    \\
\hline
 \text{change}  & -y & -y  & +y   & +y  \\
\hline
 p_{\text{eq}}   & x-y & x-y  & y   & y   \\
\hline
\end{array}$

So we find that $2(x-y+y)=1.5 \Rightarrow x = 0.75$ bar, as required.

Comment: If you want to use the [ICE matrix algorithm](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Equilibria/Le_Chatelier's_Principle/Ice_Tables) you should know how to derive the equations and understand the physics behind it.